# QGIS: How to change symbology of a continuous raster to discrete with unequal intervals?

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, qgis-2.10

I'm new in QGIS and currently trying to convert my ArcGIS-layers into QGIS.

One of these layers is a slope gradient raster. I want to change the symbology so that a specific rang of gradients will be shown as one specific color in the map (pic on the right) instead of there being continuous colors (pic on the left).

[image: left: QGIS; right: ArcGIS - desired symbology]

I tried using the "singleband pseudocolor" rendering type, but the problem is that I only seem to be able to use *equal* intervals. Is there any way to use unequal intervals for my raster style?

Comment: You can manually specify the values in the style dialog. It is a bit tricky but with trial and error you should be able to solve it that way. Or did you already try that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be accomplished by manually defining the values for the classes. After choosing the "singleband pseudocolor" renderer, now you can press the 'plus sign' just above the value window and add custom classes and change the colors. You can also just hit the classify button and then double click the populated values and change them to the desired value. Also if there are value ranges you dont want to show just set the opacity to '0' in the change color interface.

[image]