# QGIS Elevation Classification by Intervals

Tags: qgis, elevation

I am trying to classify the elevation of the information on a raster by intervals. Right now I am only able to produce a continuous band of color.

How can one display the elevation information like this:
[elevation map.](http://www.mappery.com/map-of/Afghanistan-Elevation-Map)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157433/qgis-how-to-change-symbology-of-a-continuous-raster-to-discrete-with-unequal-in. If you're using newer QGIS versions (e.g. 2.18) then you can also try the layer styling dock way I've illustrated below.

Comment: It was in fact a problem with the versions of QGis, I was unable to do that in the previous version. Even with discrete interpolation.
Thank you for your time.
Regards.

Comment: What old version of QGIS were you using? It might be good to put that information down here (e.g. I was using QGIS Version 2.1x) in case someone has the same issue in the future :)

Comment: Yes it would. But the fact is that I've upgraded without paying attention to the previous version. I guess it was 2.14 but I can't know for sure. What I can say is that upgrading to the latest version did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

On the layer styling tab (or right click on raster and select Properties), choose render type as 'Singleband pseudocolour'. There you can set interpolation to 'discrete' and use Mode 'Equal interval' and set the number of classes (see screenshot below):

[image]

You can individually change those colours in the boxes to ones you see fit, and even adjust the value ranges.

Comment: Ok the problem was the previous version of QGis, it was not working. I have updated to the new version of QGis 2.18.7. and it seems to work as you explained. Thank you for having the time. Kind regards.